# Can AMD DxcCache, DxCache, Dx9Cache cache files be shared across users?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, disk-space, directx, amd-graphics-card

On Windows 10, playing games mostly from Steam and Epic, **multiple users have large cache files in %AppData%\Local\AMD, eg %AppData%\Local\AMD\DxCache**. Across 4 users playing the same games, the DX (which I assume is DirectX) cache files amount to 20GB, 5GB each.

AIUI these are shader cache files mostly. Presumably the shader files are common to a game played on a particular system (RX6700 XT) and so there will be a lot of duplication across these directories?

Can I make a link (eg `mklink`; I'm using an NTFS filesystem) between these directories, use `cacls` to give each user permission and then have **shaders that are cached be shared across users?** (Obviously, each user account uses the files exclusively for the use time. I'm not asking about remote access.)

My guess is that whilst the shaders are duplicates, they will be *indexed* differently for each user and so won't be able to be shared. That my idea would just create a single directory with 4-times the shaders; or cause inefficient caching.

I'm not a Windows native, on Linux I'd just try it, but on Windows it seems much harder coordinating accounts. **Perhaps someone knows if this will work, please?**

Comment: A simple test... Empty the caches under both users, run the program on one user and then on the other user, and then use some [hash tool as is part of Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.3) to check whether the contents of the files are identical. If they are identical then the only issue with sharing them is the cross-user security issue as noted by Markus but if you trust the other users then that may well be irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, like I said I'm not Windows native and permissions always seems to break stuff -- so I thought someone would know already and that would be easier. Thinking now, checking "last accessed" should see if the different users used the same file; hashing to check if the only reason it doesn't work is indexing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That makes no sense at all. These are shader caches, and thus inherently very much bound to what software is using shaders, in which order, and how. They could be accessed concurrently, and even if they weren't, they contain *code* that another user will execute, so sharing them is a blatant violation of user separation.

So, no.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have a reference for how DX does shader caching? The software running, and the hardware, is all the same. If I run a game, CS2 say, on a Windows profile UserA then I switch Windows profile to UserB, login as the same Steam user and then run the same game again it seems like the shader caching would be duplicated? Yes, there would be a violation of user profile separation, but I don't care about that on this home system; like oh no my relative can see what shaders I cached??

Comment: No, it's not duplicate, at least not necessarily. Simple as that – what shaders get cached in which order is a function of in which order which software gets executed (that includes the acute gameplay) You cannot share these caches. Full stop. And no, it's not "your relative can see what shaders get cached". It's "your relative can make you execute their code, giving them full access to your data".

Comment: Note that these are just caches. You can instruct your driver interface to empty them – with no downside but a game loading slower next time. I'm honestly a bit confused why we're even discussing sharing them. (I've answered the question "can shaders caches be shared" with a clear no, which is what you asked about).  Also, we're talking about 20 GB. Seriously.

Comment: <<It's "your relative can make you execute their code, giving them full access to your data">> yes, we don't care about this. You've answered clearly, but with no references or anything, so this isn't considered a proper answer on SE/SU. If you add a reference, eg from DX documentation then I can mark it as an answer, in due time. Thanks. If you can fill in why shader caches differ for the same game profile, same game, same software and hardware environment, then that would help to fill out the answer too. Cheers.

Comment: you're moving goalposts. Have a nice day.

Comment: FWIW this [comment on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/0/3283695222739779984/#c3283695222739954712) indicates shader caches can in theory be shared across users. This comment says [shader cache files are dependent on game+GPU only](https://myhightech.org/posts/20201031-steam-shader-precompile/). [Steam Deck reportedly shares shader cache files](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/what-is-a-shader-cache-and-why-does-it-take-so-long-to-compile/176196/4) amongst all users (what I want to do).

Comment: Steam deck has control over its graphics stack. That's different. The comments you cite state "theoretically it should be possible", but it's not – that would only work if programs would be expected to generate the same shaders on different runs. But that's not the case – which shaders a game loads obviously depends on what things you play through, and which end up in a cache depends on order. So, honestly, it's awfully nice that you want to disprove my answer, but that doesn't help you.

Comment: "which shaders a game loads obviously depends on what things you play through" // not obvious sorry, the sources I found all suggested shader cache files were dependent on game+GPU, which is constant here. A source for your assertion would help, as it goes against what I found (and what I thought I knew about graphics processing). The question has been marked as "shows no research", I wanted to show I had done research.